# Displaying the title based on slider item that is in center

Tags: javascript, css

I have a slider (owl slider - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/index.html) . The slider has images as items, displaying 3 items per slide. Above the slider I have a title which will change when certain item from the slider is active.

```
<h6>
  PROJECT PARTNERS <!-- this should changed to LOCAL PARTNER when 5th ITEM is active -->
</h6>
<div id="partner" class="partners owl-carousel">

    <div class="item">
      <img  src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/grey-1.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="150" height="150" alt="Partner"/>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/grey-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="150" height="110" alt="Partner"/>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img  src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/grey-3.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="300" height="50" alt="Partner"/>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img  src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/grey-4.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="300" height="50" alt="Partner"/>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img  src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/grey-5.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="300" height="50" alt="Partner"/>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img  src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/grey-6.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="300" height="50" alt="Partner"/>
    </div>


 </div>



<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

          jQuery('.partners').owlCarousel({
                    center: false,
                    items:1,
                    loop:false,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    margin:70,
                    responsive:{
                  600:{
                        items:3,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    margin:200
                }
            }
    });



</script>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: From a UX point-of-view you shouldn't do it like you are trying to achieve. If you insist on using carousels, better use two carousels: one for the Project Partners and the other for the Local Partners.

Comment: But to do it like you are trying: Check the Events section in the Owl documentation: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html and use `event.item.index` in the event callback

Comment: @yunzen Ok.. need to check the docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.partners').owlCarousel({
     center: false,
     items: 1,
     loop: false,
     autoWidth: true,
     margin: 70,
     responsive: {
         600:{
             items:3,
             autoWidth: true,
             margin:200
         }
     },
     onChange: function (event) {
         console.log(event);
         if (event.item.index == 2) {
             $("h6").text("chnaged title");
         }
    }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vdqj60a5/1/

Comment: not exactly what I want. But I can have some idea. Thanks.